# Use GCloud Compute Windows instance as git remote server

Tags: windows, git, google-cloud-platform, continuous-integration, continuous-delivery

I have a running Windows instance on Google Cloud Compute Engine and I installed git on it.

I need to get my code (when pushed to Gitlab) to also push to the Instance and run the build script. I tried searching for how to automate this with CI/CD, but I couldn't figure it out.

Now I am resorting to using the instance as a remote for my local branch so I can easily push to it. I have not been able to figure this out also because ssh is not available on windows instances. I need help.